# Android Studio Error: Unknown Host

Tags: android

I know this has been asked many times but I can not find the right solution.

I updated my Android studio from 2.3.3 to 3.0.1. 
Then I started facing this error.

```
Unknown host 'This is usually a temporary error during hostname resolution and means that the local server did not receive a response from an authoritative server'. You may need to adjust the proxy settings in Gradle.

Enable Gradle 'offline mode' and sync project

Learn about configuring HTTP proxies in Gradle
```

When I click on "Enable offline mode", get the following error:

```
Error:No cached version of com.android.tools.build:gradle:4.2.1 available for offline mode.
Disable Gradle 'offline mode' and sync project
```

I have tried to set the proxy, and tried to use it on offline mode.I have even used VPN and tried to bypass proxy, but it is not working.

Comment: read the message you get: **DISABLE OFFLINE MODE AND SYNC PROJECT**

Comment: Please see: [Why is “Can someone help me?” not an actual question?](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/284236)